# JavaScript (node.js) How to get the URL of a random image from a subreddit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, reddit

Basically, I'm trying to get the URL of a random picture from a specific subreddit. I've tried using the raw JSON [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json), but I can't quite figure it out. I've been using snekfetch to get the JSON, since it's worked before on [less complicated sites](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), but I've seen other methods like superagent and snoowrap that I don't have any idea how to use properly. Here's what I've tried using snekfetch (I'm trying to incorporate this into a discord bot):

```
case "pic":
    if (!args[1]) return message.channel.send("Enter a title (Be VERY specific");
    // pics was set equal to "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics.json" earlier
    snekfetch.get(pics).then(r => {
        let postTitle = args[1];
        let img = r.preview.images[0].source.url;
        let entry = r.find(post => post.title == postTitle);
        let picture = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setAuthor(entry.title)
            .addField(entry)
            .setImage(img);
        message.channel.send(picture);
        //message.channel.send(entry.preview.images[0].source.url);
    });
    break;
```

I'm new to JSON, so it wouldn't surprise me if this code is full of horrible mistakes.

Through some googling, I managed to find that apparently each reddit post has an ID in base 36. But these ID's aren't actually in order, so I'd need to store them all in an array and randomly select from that.

In short, how do I retrieve an image from reddit as a URL, and how do I put a certain amount of these images into an array?

Answer (score 0):

Using the JSON data provided you can get all of the images using something like this:

```
async function getImages(url) {
    const images = [];
    const response = await snekfetch.get(url);
    response.body.data.children.forEach((child) => {
        child.data.preview.images.forEach((image) => {
            images.push(image.source.url);
        });
    });
    return images;
}
```

If you need to only gather `N` images, then you may want to use a standard for loop that breaks when `N === images.length`.